# How to override generics correctly in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

We have ancestor class with some properties (example with React).

```
export interface AncestorProps<T> {
    ...    
}

export class Ancestor<T> extends React.Component<AncestorProps<T>> {    
}
```

How to override child component correctly?

```
interface DescendentProps extends AncestorProps {
    someFunction: () => void;
}

export class Descendent<T> extends Ancestor<DescendentProps<T>> {
}
```

because not working, so I received this error (I remind you that this is React):

> [ts] Type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> &
>   Readonly>>' has no property
>   'someFunction' and no string index signature.

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-spovvh?file=index.tsx)

Comment: What does *not working* mean? The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @estus Sorry :( Forgot to paste error output. Fixed

Comment: The code doesn't cause this error. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-evfd65

Comment: Added `someFunction` calling. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ojgz3j

Comment: What purpose does `T` serve?

Comment: Ancestor is generic from legacy code. I need declare descendent class which extending this generic

Comment: You can't without modifying it or making it dirty. Normally, React component should accept props type as generic param. In your case `T` doesn't serve this purpose, while `Ancestor` is hard-coded to `AncestorProps` props. Please, provide MCVE. It's unclear what your really code really is and thus it's hard to suggest how it should be modified, generic params in particular.

Comment: Ok. So simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-spovvh?file=index.tsx. I want to override `Ancestor` and use `DescendentProps` in `Descendent`

Comment: Consider adding it to the question in addition to existing example, the problem will be more clear for readers to understand. I'll provide an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with these generics is that they break the convention for `React.Component` to accept props and state as generic parameters. Parent class cannot be extended like `Ancestor<DescendentProps<T>>` because generic parameter is not props type in `Ancestor` but something else.

A fix would be to redefine `props` type in child class:

```
export interface AncestorProps<T> {}

export class Ancestor<T> extends React.Component<AncestorProps<T>> {}

interface DescendentProps<T> extends AncestorProps<T> {
    someFunction: () => void;
}

export class Descendent<T> extends Ancestor<T> {
  props!: DescendentProps<T>;
}
```

A proper way to make this hierarchy extendable is to consistently follow the convention for prop and state generic parameters. If there's no need for `T` parameter in `AncestorProps<T>`, it should be discarded:

```
export interface AncestorProps {}

export class Ancestor<P extends AncestorProps, S = {}> extends React.Component<P, S> {}

interface DescendentProps extends AncestorProps {
    someFunction: () => void;
}

export class Descendent<P extends DescendentProps, S = {}> extends Ancestor<P, S> {}
```